# need help installing extensions

Tags: extensions, marketplace

I am having a lot of trouble installing extentions on my magento 2 platform. I can't come up with a solution.

in my root folder of magento installation I modified the composer.json I added the following lines to require: "magevision/module-admin-category-product-thumbnail":"2.4.2"

then i gave in the composer the following command: "composer require magevision/module-admin-category-product-thumbnail:2.4.2"
I then get the message "root composer.json requires magevision/module-admin-category-thumbnail 2.4.2 -> satisfiable at [magevision/module-admin-category-thumbnail 2.4.2].

magevision/module-admin-category-thumbnail 2.4.2 requires magento/framework 103.0.* -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

who can help me? I just can't install extentions for example from magemarketplace.

i hope someone can tell me what to do and maybe tell me step by step how to install extentions? do i have to make me sudo and if so how do i do that? i think i have installed composer the right way.

Thanks for the effort.